# Writing cleaner Promise completion closure

Tags: angular, promise, subscribe

New to Angular and promises, but I've realized I've done this a lot:

```
this.myService.createFoo(data).subscribe(
  (result: any) => {
    resolve({success: true, data: result});
  },
  err => {
    resolve({success: false, message: err});
  });

this.myService.updateFoo(data).subscribe(
  (result: any) => {
    resolve({success: true, data: result});
  },
  err => {
    resolve({success: false, message: err});
  });
```

How would I rewrite the completion closure for my subscribe method so that I don't repeat code like this?. Thanks!

Comment: You could try using `async` and `await` but I'm not sure how easily that will be to slip into what you're doing (not super familiar with angular or subscribe) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: How are `resolve` and `reject` defined? Are those coming from the `Promise` constructor, like `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})`, or somewhere else? Might help if you posted a slightly more inclusive code sample.

Comment: Yes, it's just like the normal `new promise ....` like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to extract your callbacks into generic functions and just pass those:

```
const successHandler = (data: any) => resolve({success: true, data });
const errorHandler = (message) => resolve({success: false, message });

this.myService.createFoo(data).subscribe(successHandler, errorHandler);
this.myService.updateFoo(data).subscribe(successHandler, errorHandler);
```

If you want to define these outside of the scope of the `Promise` (which I assume the code you posted is inside of), you could curry the handlers:

**some-util-library.js**

```
const handlers = resolve => ({
    success: (data: any) => resolve({success: true, data }),
    error: (message) => resolve({success: false, message })
});
export { handlers };
```

**otherfile.js**

```
import { handlers } from './some-util-library.js';
... other code
const { success, error } = handlers(resolve);
this.myService.createFoo(data).subscribe(success, error);
this.myService.updateFoo(data).subscribe(success, error);
```

Comment: Can you just use `resolve` like that, or do you have to specify it as a parameter?

Comment: Good question, it wasn't obvious in the code OP posted where `resolve` was coming from, so I assumed it was available from a parent scope or as a global

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to return a promise, and that the code you posted is contained in a method that looks something like this:

```
create(): Promise<any> {
  const data = 'whatever';
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.myService.createFoo(data).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        resolve({ success: true, data: result });
      },
      err => {
        resolve({ success: false, message: err });
      });
  });
}
```

If that's the case, rather than manually creating a promise, you can turn your Observable into a promise using the `toPromise` operator. You will need to import it first if you haven't already:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Then, combining it with `async` and `await`, you can transform your code as follows:

```
async create(): Promise<any> {
  const data = 'whatever';
  try {
    const result = await this.myService.createFoo(data).toPromise();
    return { success: true, data: result }
  } catch (err) {
    return { success: false, message: err };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the perfect use case for [Angular HttpClient Interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses)